# Swift. Mostrar alertas rápidas en iOS

Tags: ios, swift2

Necesito mostrar en swift alertas rápidas como las de la app de música.

Como se llama este tipo de vista?

Gracias!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si quieres una alerta nativa , utiliza **UIAlertController** sin embargo si quieres tirar de alguna librería externa para utilizar imágenes en las alertas por ejemplo , te dejo una en Swift con un ejemplo de uso , se llama **APESuperHUD**

```
APESuperHUD.showOrUpdateHUD(icon: .CheckMark, message: message, duration: duration, presentingView: view, completion:nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Este tipo de alertas no son nativas del sistema y por tanto has de utilizar librerías de terceros.
Una de las mejores para dicha tarea es [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD). 
Es simple de utilizar y altamente configurable.

Comment: Entiendo! pensé que al ser utilizada por apple music era nativa. Muchas gracias!